# Problems in the barcode of impression (Zebra)

Tags: java, printing, barcode, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

I am having trouble printing a certain type of bar code on the Zebra printer.

This is the command to print ( Language CPCL )

```
B I2OF5 1 2 120 5 1700 00190000090125290700900092817170756010000049177
```

I took this very ZEBRA 's code documentation , however , it does not work for me.
I'm thinking it may be a source or something, because the documentation does not say anything about it.

Comment: Which Zebra printer are you targeting?

Comment: Hi , I'm using the printer RW 420 Mobile Printer

Comment: The strange thing is that putting another type of bar code (128 for example) it works .. the problem is the type " I2OF5 "